# Evaluate and measure, which one is appropriate when refer to people?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Which one is appropriate?

- How do you evaluate yourself?
- How do you measure yourself?

Can someone explain what is different between them? Please give me much example as possible.

Comment: How do you see yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Measuring* typically involves gathering raw, typically more physical data. In the context of a person, "measuring oneself" would probably involve things like height, girth, perhaps weight, and so on - although in that context "how do you measure yourself" is not idiomatic, unless you're taking it literally as "in what way do you determine your own height".

*Evaluating* is drawing conclusions from the observations, and I'd say it's acceptable for eg. your boss to ask you in a performance review "how do you evaluate yourself?" It rings a bit unnatural to me - "how do you see/view yourself" or "how would you evaluate your performance" are better alternatives - but it's not incorrect.